# Java arrays - How to go through List and set specific value

Tags: java, arrays, list

First i add new Popotnik in List popotnik depending on how big it is, which is working fine - function prostaMesta. Then i want to go through list popotnik and set popotnik value depending on where it is in for, but value of i will always be 0 everytime it is being called. Also i have break there as i only want to set one popotnik at the time. How should i increment (i) while having some sort of break in there?

Also  `if(popotnik.get(i) == null){}` is not being called, but values inside popotnik are null(s)

```
private List<Popotnik> popotnik = new ArrayList<Popotnik>();

public void prostaMesta(List<Popotnik> popotnik, int sedez){
            stanovanje.setPostle(sedez);
            for(int i=0; i<stanovanje.getPostle(); i++){
                popotnik.add(new Popotnik());
            }
            System.out.println(popotnik);
        }

public void dodajPotnika(List<Popotnik> popotnik, Popotnik popotnik2){
    for(int i=0; i<popotnik.size(); i++){
        if(popotnik.get(i) == null){
            setPopotnik(popotnik, i);
            popotnik.set(i, popotnik2);
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(getPopotnik());
}

public void setPopotnik(List<Popotnik> popotnik, int i){
    this.popotnik = popotnik;
}


public List<Popotnik> getPopotnik(){
    return popotnik;
}
```

Main class:

```
  List<Popotnik> alPopotnik = new ArrayList<Popotnik>();

    if(x.equals("p")){ //inside of a loop when prostaMesta() is being called
        potovanje.prostaMesta(alPopotnik, sedez);
    }

    `if(x.equals("d")){` //inside of a loop when dodajPotnika() is being called
            System.out.println("Vnesi ime: ");
            String ime = skener.next();
            Popotnik popotnik = new Popotnik(ime);
            potovanje.dodajPotnika(alPopotnik, popotnik);   
     }
```

Comment: What is the code behind `setPopotnik(popotnik, i);` ? Because we won't be able to help you if we don't have it. And i'd like to point out that modifying an input value, instead of returning it can really be ambiguous for those working with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if(popotnik.get(i) == null)` is never true because objects on the list are not null. You initialize them in the for loop in prostaMesta.
If you have some fields inside the Popotnik class then they are null, but object itself is not.

You would need to do something like `popotnik.get(i).getName() == null`.

Besides, if you only want to add a number at the end of popotnik's name then it isn't necessary to initialize a list with empty objects.
You could just add objects to list using a different constructor.
For example `popotnik.add(new Popotnik("Popotnik"+(popotnik.size()+1)))`.
It's not pretty but I think initialization like this here is not necessary.